# Не срабатывает хук woocommerce_product_is_in_stock

Tags: php, woocommerce

Если на странице корзины у товара количество 0, то срабатывает проверка и выкидывается исключение

```
        if ( ! $product_data->has_enough_stock( $quantity ) ) {
            /* translators: 1: product name 2: quantity in stock */
            throw new Exception( sprintf( __( 'You cannot add that amount of &quot;%1$s&quot; to the cart because there is not enough stock (%2$s remaining).', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_name(), wc_format_stock_quantity_for_display( $product_data->get_stock_quantity(), $product_data ) ) );
        }
public function has_enough_stock( $quantity ) {
    return ! $this->managing_stock() || $this->backorders_allowed() || $this->get_stock_quantity() >= $quantity;
}
```

но мне нужно чтобы при определённых условиях это исключение не срабатывало.

Как переопределить это исключение?

Comment: Добавить эти условия в if. О чем вопрос вообще...

Comment: нет, это я привёл код, как сейчас обрабатываются события, если у товара количество 0.
вобщем там нужно переопределять два события: `woocommerce_product_is_in_stock` и `woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity`

Comment: решил проблему, сделал return true в этих событиях